# Multiple websites scraping with BeautifulSoup and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I'm trying to scrape multiple e-commerce websites with BeautifulSoup and Selenium.

I use the CSS Selector of search box in that websites and search for a word then try to scrape related data with BeautifulSoup.But a can't implement one code to scrape all these websites.

I can scrape the data I need from each website but i can't do this for all of them with one code.

My target is having one code and scrape data from multiple e-commerce websites.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: when the data and page code is different for each page then i think you need to create separate scraper for each page.

Comment: When the number of pages increases, it is not possible to create separate scraper for each page.